# Regexp negative check of word in group

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

My template is here:

https://regex101.com/r/6z8X43/3

My issue is Second group in Match 7:

`([^\/\n]*)`

this.text = text;

It means any characters, except / or "new line" untill .text

But I need to add "this" word to this negative check, so `this.text` should be invalid. Something like `([^\/\n|this]*)` - not /, not \n and not exactly "this".

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using regex to parse actual code (your compiler certainly doesn't...it uses a formal parser).

Comment: Use another RegEx and invert the result.

Comment: Tim Biegeleisen, I work in Intellij Idea. It can apply refactoring using regexp. It works great now, except "this" case.

Comment: iBug, Can you show some example?

Comment: Try something like this `((?!this)[^\/\n])*` https://regex101.com/r/6z8X43/4

Comment: For the record, `[^\/\n|this]` means *"match a single character which is not `/` or `\n` or `|` or `t` or `h` or `i` or `s`".* Generally, don't use square brackets until you understand what they do.

Comment: tripleee, It was example how it may be. Sure thing I`ve tested it and got your results =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
^([ \f\t]*)((?:(?!this)[^\/\n])*)\.text\s*=[ \f\t]*([^$;\n=]+)
#                ^^^^^
```

See [**your modified demo**](https://regex101.com/r/6z8X43/5).